# How do i fsck / on solaris 10?

Tags: solaris, fsck

```
[ID 879645 kern.notice] NOTICE: /: unexpected free inode 211471, run fsck(1M) -o f
```

How can i run fsck cleanly (/ unmounted) ?
The only solutions i can see are:
- detach the SDS mirror, fsck on the other metadevice, reboot on it, and sync back the mirror;
- boot on a CDROM and run fsck (hope the CD will handle the RAID).

Is there a ways to force Solaris 10 to run fsck on next reboot ?
How do you fsck your / on Solaris 10 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the ok prompt:

```
boot -m milestone=none
```

should do it

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go.

Comment: OK, i've done that, but fsck'ing / while still mount rw does not fill alright.

Comment: OBP is present only in SPARC machines. I would use boot -s to boot in single user mode and then fsck the filesystem. Is there a difference?

Comment: At that point, nothing is running in the system that will be writing to disk, so it's safe.  Reboot afterward.  On an x86 system, you can do a 'reboot -- -m milestone=none' or 'reboot -- -s' to do the same thing, I'd have thought.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately,
    boot -m milestone=none
didn't work for us; we simply got the same recurring error message on boot.

Instead, we had to take the "boot on a CDROM and run fsck" route.  Oracle has a detailed doc on it called [How to Check the root (/), /usr, or /var File Systems From an Alternate Boot Device](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5093/fstroublefsck-59/index.html)